# Update value of object with values in different array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array with below structure:
Array1:

```
[{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"330gm",rate:"100"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"450gm",rate:"200"}]
```

Array2:

```
[{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"600gm",rate:"300"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"800gm",rate:"500"}]
```

result

```
Array1 =[{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"330gm",rate:"300"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"450gm",rate:"500"}]
```

I want to be able to update the only rates of objects in Array1 with rate of objects in Array2.

Comment: Can you explain what is the exact problem.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Array1 = Array1.map(item => {
      Array2.map(rec => {
        if (rec._id === item._id) {
          return { ...rec, rate: item.rate };
        } else {
          return;
        }
      });
    });

Comment: I tried this it returns [undefined,undefined]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order or lengths of the arrays are different one efficient way is
create a Map of the new rates from Array2 then loop over Array1 ant `get()` from the Map.

This way you only iterate `Array2` once instead of using multiple iterations of methods like `find()`

```js
let Array1=[{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"330gm",rate:"100"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"450gm",rate:"200"}],
    Array2=[{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"600gm",rate:"300"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"800gm",rate:"500"}];

const rateMap = new Map(Array2.map(({id, rate})=> [id, rate]));
Array1.forEach(e=> rateMap.has(e.id) && (e.rate = rateMap.get(e.id )))

console.log(Array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Array1 = [
    {id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"330gm",rate:"100"}, 
    {id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"450gm",rate:"200"}
];

let Array2 = [
    {id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"600gm",rate:"300"}, 
    {id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"800gm",rate:"500"}
];

for (i = 0; i < Array1.length ; i++) {
    Array1[i].rate = Array2[i].rate
}

console.log(Array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution I came up with.
But as charlietfl said: I make assumtion that both lengths are the same and in same order

```js
let array1 = [{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"330gm",rate:"100"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"450gm",rate:"200"}]
let array2 = [{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"600gm",rate:"300"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"800gm",rate:"500"}]

array1.updateRate = function(array2) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.length;i++) {
        console.log(this[i].rate)
        this[i].rate = array2[i].rate;
        console.log(this[i].rate)
    }
}

array1.updateRate(array2);
console.log(array1)
```

Here is second (full) solution, where that asumption isn't made:

```js
let array1 = [{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"330gm",rate:"100"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"450gm",rate:"200"}]
let array2 = [{id:1234,name:"macaron",quantity:"600gm",rate:"300"},{id:5678,name:"Gelato",quantity:"800gm",rate:"500"}]

array1.updateRate = function(array2) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.length;i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < array2.lenght;j++) {
            if(this[i].id === array2[j].id) {
                this[i].rate = array2[j].rate;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

array1.updateRate(array2);
console.log(array2)
```

Comment: Note this makes assumption that array lengths are the same and in same order

Answer (score 0):

```
Array1 = Array1.map(item => { 
            return { ...item, rate: Array2.filter(rec => rec.id === item.id)[0].rate }; 
       }); 
});
```